# Coleman ct200u ex running

Tags: throttle

I just put a stage 1 performabce air intake kit, carb that's meant for it, and it doesn't properly run. It starts fine and everything was put on correctly. After half a second of trying to give it gas it cuts off. Everything looks fine and hoses are good. Only thing im not sure if us the throttle adjuster. When you pull on the handlebar throttle the springs that pull the throttle barely move. Did the new carb have a different size then the old one to make slack in it?

Comment: We cannot tell you that. Did you buy the correct kit? Did you make the recommended adjustments that come with that kit? It is a concern that the throttle springs barely move.

Comment: Yes I bought the air performance kit for the Coleman specifically and looked online on other videos of install and its the same. The carb was a suggestion when I bought the perfomance kit. It said it runs better with that then the stock carb. Even though it said its a Honda cyclone carb I ran the numbers and its the one that the performance kit listed that would be a good combo. Just now the throttle cable isn't pulling enough and etc. Still starts up